# Is there different scala lock synchronized usage?

Tags: java, scala, synchronized

I learned that in scala we can use synchronized like next

1. synchronized(Object)
2. function with synchronized

However i found some codes

```
Object synchronized{
....
}


lock = new Object
lock synchronized{
....
}
```

do they work same? or work differently?

actually i tried to find special grammers but i couldn't find them

i need docs or pages to check it

Comment: This is nether valid Java nor Scala so it's hard to tell what this code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

In the JVM any Object can be used as a lock, and often we want just a lock so we create an empty lock object. We can then synchronize on it, as opposed to other usage of synchronize without an explicit lock object which synchronize on "this" implicitly.

you can take any object let's call it "lock" as in your example and do
lock.synchronized {
...
}

in your example there is also use of scala infix notation which can confuse some to avoid the "."